# How to write a code to have a Vertical line for trading session during 12:00 pm and 1:00 pm in Pine Editor?

Tags: session, pine-script, trading

1. Vertical Line in the chart
2. For a trading session during 12:00 to 13:00 on chart

Answer (score 0):

You can use bgcolor function to set the vertical background color where hour is between 12 and 13. Example

```
//@version = 5
indicator(title="test",overlay = true)
bgcolor(hour>=12 and hour<13?color.new(color.red,70):na)
```

[image]